# Custom property and communicating data between view-models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a simple app that has a control that defines player's name and their style. This control is reused for player 1 and player 2. The first goal is to set two radio button groups so that each player gets to select accordingly. The second is to communicate the data from this control to the main page's view model. How do I accomplish these things?

Here's what the control looks like:

[image]

The following is the project structure:

[image]

Player.cs simply holds reference to the player's style and their name

```
namespace temp
{
    class Player
    {
        // offensive / defensive
        public string Style { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It also acts as the view model for PlayerInfoControl. Here's the code for it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="temp.Controls.PersonInfoControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:temp.Controls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:temp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:Player x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <RadioButton Content="Offense" GroupName="{Binding Group}" />
                <RadioButton Content="Defense" GroupName="{Binding Group}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,15,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Name" />
                <TextBox Width="100" Height="25" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow is a simple grid that defines the playerInfoControl twice

```
<Window x:Class="temp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:temp"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:temp.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="160" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:PersonInfoControl Grid.Row="0" Group="p1" />
        <controls:PersonInfoControl Grid.Row="1" Group="p2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Lastly, there's MainWindowViewModel that I need to relay the data to, that's captured by PlayInfoControl.

```
namespace temp
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        Player Player1 = new Player();
        Player Player2 = new Player();
    }
}
```

I'm first trying to solve setting the group. I created a custom dependency property, however by app fails to build because of it and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public partial class PersonInfoControl : UserControl
    {
        public PersonInfoControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Group
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(GroupProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GroupProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Group.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Group", typeof(string), typeof(Player), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
```

This is what the error looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct type for the default value of your dependency property. In your case its `0` which cannot be assigned to a string. Replace

```
new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

with

```
new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

Comment: MainWindow.xaml is complaining that "Player type must derive from DependencyObject"

Comment: I extended Player : DependencyObject and the groups are working fine now! How do I pass data that I'm collecting with Player.cs to MainWindowViewModel.cs?